# has no method 'getElementsByTagName' error makes no sense

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

i alert(xmldoc) in it is there? i dont understand
here the code:

```
function getChatText()
{
   if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) 
   {
      receiveReq.open("GET", 'getChat.php', true);
      receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleReceiveChat; 
      receiveReq.send(null);
   }
}   

function handleReceiveChat()
{
   if (receiveReq.readyState == 4)
   {
      var chat_div = document.getElementById('div_chat');
      var xmldoc = receiveReq.responseText;
      alert(xmldoc);
      var message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message"); 
      var n_messages = message_nodes.length
      //more code here
   }
}
```

part of getChat.php looks like this:

```
<?php
//code here
  $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>';
  $sql = "SELECT message_id, user_name, message, date_format(post_time, '%h:%i') as post_time" . 
    " FROM message WHERE chat_id = " . db_input($_GET['chat']) ;
  $message_query = db_query($sql);
  while($message_array = db_fetch_array($message_query)) 
  {
$xml .= '<message>';
    $xml .= '<message_id id= "' . $message_array['message_id'] . '"</message_id>';
$xml .= '<user>' . htmlspecialchars($message_array['user_name']) . '</user>';
$xml .= '<text>' . htmlspecialchars($message_array['message']) . '</text>';
$xml .= '<time>' . $message_array['post_time'] . '</time>';
$xml .= '</message>';
  }
}
echo $xml;
?>
```

the exact error is on:

```
var message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message");
```

and states:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object `<?xml version="1.0" ?><message><message_id id= "1"</message_id><user>Me, ME, me and mE </user><text>123</text><time>09:14</time></message>` has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

can some one please explain this?
thank you

Comment: Isn't a tagname called "message" a bit weird in the first place?

Comment: i didnt pick the name im doing a tutorial: http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/Sending_AJAX_Chat_Request-271_290_291_293.html

Answer (score 1):

`xmldoc` seems to be a string (`receiveReq.responseText`), not a DOM element. Strings don't have the `getElementsByTagName` method.

Try [`receiveReq.responseXML` *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsexml-attribute), this returns a DOM `Document` object.

See also: [XMLHttpRequest *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest)

**Update:** I took the XML as it is shown in your post, and ran it through http://validator.w3.org/check.

You XML is not correct, that's why you get `null`. This is not valid:

```
<message_id id= "1"</message_id>
```

Seems you are missing a `>`. If you are generating that XML manually, then don't. Use a proper XML document builder.

Comment: i have this function as well:

    var sendReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    function getXmlHttpRequestObject()
    {
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {
          return new XMLHttpRequest();  //chrome
       } 
    }
responseXML gives error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

please see my other comments 
thank you

Comment: @Helloise: Is the XML wellformed? If it returns `null` it seems that it cannot be parsed.

Comment: yikes please see main code at the top, i added the xml cos there not enough characters available to post it here :)

Comment: @Helloise: As I said, you are missing the `>` (before `</message_id>`): `'<message_id id= "' . $message_array['message_id'] . '"></message_id>';`

Comment: i added the > and kept my code to receiveReq.responseText and alert(xmldoc) gives:
    <?xml version="1.0" ?><message><message_id id= "1"></message_id><user>Me, ME, me and mE </user><text>123</text><time>09:14</time></message>

i change to receiveReq.responseXML and get error:  Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null and alert(xmldoc) is null

yikes i dont know..what else can be wrong?

Comment: @Helloise: You have to fix the XML **and** use `responseXML`. A string does not have a `getElementsByTagName` method. You have to tell the browser to treat the response as XML document and that is what `responseXML` is doing.

Comment: thanks Felix, i have added the part where the xml is made up it is in getChat.php at the top with all my other code  

would it be better to have that part in a proper .xml doc rather? the only q now is how do i call the .xml doc and loop through it in getChat.php??

Comment: @Helloise: You are generating the XML dynamically form the DB, so storing it somewhere does not make sense. Have a look at [`SimpleXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for creating XML documents.

Comment: i went through that code but there the values are hardcoded..it is not retrieved from a db..how else must i make up my xml?

Comment: @HelloiseSmit let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2530/discussion-between-felix-kling-and-helloise-smit)

Answer (score 0):

The responseText (xmldoc) is a string. Strings have methods, but getElementByTagName is not one of them.

getElementByTagName is a method of objects, not strings. eg

```
var numberOfAnchorTagsInADocument = document.getElementByTagName("a").length;
```

Please provide more info on what you're trying to do.

Comment: To be more precise, `getElementByTagName` is a method of DOM elements.

Comment: You're right, but I didn't know if that would be understood as easily. I clarified on the usage rather than the definition.

Comment: i am following this tutorial: 
http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/Sending_AJAX_Chat_Request-271_290_291_293.html 

i changed var xmldoc = receiveReq.responseText; to responseXML and NOW get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null... i dont understand?

please help?

Comment: ... I don't know exactly what you're getting parsed. Try putting this before your error _alert(receiveReq.responseText);_ What does it alert?

Comment: i get the contents of my table as(will only put 1st line): 

    <?xml version="1.0" ?><message><message_id id= "1"></message_id><user>Me, ME, me and mE </user><text>123</text><time>09:14</time></message>

i also have a header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

Answer (score 0):

You haven't sent proper response headers before sending the response in PHP... That's why the responseXML is null.

Try adding in your PHP file:-

header('Content-Type: text/xml');